# Add new column to an EAV table `catalog_product_entity`

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, mysql, eav

I tried to add new column to the table `catalog_product_entity` via a setup resource. But when i try to save a value to table (using `setMyColumnName()`), the value is not reflected in the underlying table.

I understand that this is the wrong way to add a column to an eav table in magento. But i couldn't find any article on howto do this.

**NOTE**: i don't need to add an attribute to `catalog/product`. I want to add a field as a column.

Comment: What you want to do is a static attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *i don't need to add an attribute to catalog/product. I want to add a field as a column*

You want to store entity-related data against product records? Then you *do* want to add an attribute to the product entity. That's what a column on the `catalog_product_entity` table is.

Your approach is similar to mine the first time I tried to store a new property against the `catalog_product` entity, and with the same results. The reason that your write is failing is that the property stored against your product instance (e.g. `my_column_name` via `setMyColumnName()`) is not a registered attribute for that entity. When you call `$product->save()`, the EAV resource `save()` will load each attribute configuration in order to perform the save operation - even for attributes with values stored on the entity table.

The following script will create the column (VARCHAR 255 in this case) as well as register the attribute. You will want to test that the column value is indexed with flat product enabled.

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('catalog/product'),
    'my_column_name',
    array(
        'type'    => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'  => 255,
        'comment' => 'My Column Name'
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'my_column_name',
    array(
        'label' => 'Initial Label',
        'type'  => 'static'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Is it possible to have only table columns but not attributes? I have a requirement where I added a custom tab to "product information" in which I am loading a template. this template has four input fields. I want this input fields to act same as attribute fields. I tried your solution, which is generating four attribute fields in General tab of "product information" which I don't want. please help..

Answer (score 4):

## add attribute to main table

You want to add an attribute `backend_type => 'static'` with this, the attribute is added as column to the main table

## add value in database

To add the value into the database, magento needs to know, that this column exists. `Zend_Db` caches all schemas of the tables and you need to clean the cache, to refresh this schema. So deleting everyhing in `var/cache/` should solve your problem

Comment: can you give an example ? I added `backend_type => 'static'` in my setup resource for my custom eav entity. but it is not working.

Comment: Feel free to open a new question and ping me on twitter. I don't understand your problem :)